# Swagger UI Endless Spinner On Load

Tags: c#, .net, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, .net-7.0

I am trying to implement Swashbuckle Swagger to a .NET 7 project. However, when I load the Swagger UI, I get an endless spinner. It appears to be going into some endless loop, presumably trying to create the swagger.json, as if i leave it for long enough and can watch my machine's memory get filled and then crash.

[image]

And when reviewing the call to the swagger.json file it just shows it is being fetched.

[image]

Here is the code in the Configure method of Startup.cs. I have tried altering the json path to `swagger/v1/swagger.json`, `/v1/swagger.json`, `v1/swagger.json` and event `../swagger/v1/swagger.json`, all exhibit the same behaviour.

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
     {
     c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "RackEmApp API V1");
     });
```

And this is taken from the ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
     {
          var xmlFilename = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
          c.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFilename));

          c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
          {
               Version = "v1",
               Title = "RackEmApp API",
               Description = "A Web API for developers to interact with the RackEmApp dataset for a given league/organization. This is in development and has limited support.",
                    
           });

                
       });
```

Comment: It looks like there is an issue with Swagger - https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1950

Comment: Doesn't seem linked as in that example it produces a swagger.json, mine does not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through a trial and error of deleting my controllers I identified that the issue was that I had this annotation on the Controller

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
```

And in an action within that same controller I had this

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = false)]
```

This obviously sent swagger into an endless loop. Removing it from the action fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

app.UseSwagger(c =>
{
c.RouteTemplate = "/swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json";
});
app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API"));
app.UseSwaggerUI(c => {
c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API");
c.RoutePrefix = "swagger";
});

Comment: No altering these lines did not help

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
    options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
});
```